# Input string was not in a correct format. MySQL ExecuteReader

Tags: mysql

I'm having this problem int this code:

```
using (MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Patients WHERE taj = @taj";

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("taj", DbType.String).Value = patient.Taj;

    using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        List<Patient> patients = ReadPatientsFromReader(reader);

        if (patients.Count > 0)
        {
            rvFound = patients[0];
        }
    }
}
```

I tried some advices like use "?" insead of "@" or try to not concatenate command strings. Now I'm stuck.
Appreciate your help.

[The Error i got](http://s12.postimg.org/r5en3z931/untitled.png)

Comment: `@taj` is a mysql variable. it probably should be `:taj` to be a named placeholder

Comment: @MarcB I've always though it was "funny" about MySQL as well, but according to their own documentation, he is doing that part correctly. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html

Comment: Tried with that. Still having the same problem like on the pic I attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public SqlParameter AddWithValue(
    string parameterName,
    Object value
)
```

the first parameter is the name of your parameter, so it should be:

```
AddWithValue("@taj", value)
```

source:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `patient.Taj` is a DateTime property, have you tried formatting the string added to 'YYYY-MM-DD'?

Comment: Its a simple string. Im not editing it just use it as the user typed in the text box. There are no spaces in it either.